# Firebase cloud function not writing content of wildcard, but name of wildcard

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

When I write to the realtime database with a cloud function, I keep getting "myUID" in the database instead of the content of the wildcard (the actual uid). Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Also, I have async in the function because there is other stuff that happens that I cut out before posting. The function runs and write well, but I want to write the content of myUID instead of literally writing "myUID"

```
export const userFollow = functions.database
.ref ('/user-following/{myUID}/{targetUID}')
.onCreate(async(snapshot, context) => {
    const myUID = context.params.myUID
    const targetUID = context.params.targetUID
    const ref = admin.database().ref(`/user-followers/${targetUID}`) 
    return ref.set({myUID : 1})
})
```

Comment: If you have information to add  to your question, you can simply edit it.  Don't add a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript takes the names of object properties literally when they are named as you have now.  If you want to use the value of a variable as the name of a property, use the square bracket syntax:

```
ref.set({[myUID] : 1})
```

Comment: I tried adding the square brackets, but it still writes as "myUID." I'm using TypeScript by the way, is there a difference or does it matter?

Comment: No, it's the same.

Comment: Any other reason why it might not be working even with the [ ] brackets? I'm kind of stuck here :/

Comment: No, that's the way to do it. This question comes up all the time. Make sure you deploy the code again.

Comment: It finally worked about 5 deploys later. I did deploy the first 4 times, but I don't know what was happening. Thanks!